# How to iterate over data from a file?

Tags: python, file, loops, iteration

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to figure out how to display different things from a source file. The assignment is to write a program that lets the user type in the name of a file containing test answers (A, B, C, or D) from a math class and then open that file, which I believe I have already done below. Each file has a different number of lines because each class has a different number of students. Each line contains a student's ID number and the answers they put for the test, separated by commas. Example:

```
"N12345678,B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"
```

The program should then "grade" the test by comparing the answers each student put with the answer key, which is

```
"B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"
```

The program should also determine and print out the highest score out of all the students in the text file, the lowest score, and the mean, median, mode, and range of the scores.

I already have the part written to open the file and count the number of students, but I've been trying and failing to write the section that will grade each student's answers. Here is what I have so far:

```
file_name = input("Enter a class file to grade (class1.txt, class2.txt, etc): ")
try:
    outfile = open(file_name, 'r')
    print("Successfuly opened",file_name)
    print()
except:
    print("File does not exist.")

student_counter = 0
for line in outfile:
    data = (line.rstrip('\n'))
    print(data)
    student_counter = student_counter + 1

print(student_counter)
```

And here is what I've tried for grading each student's answers, but it doesn't seem to be working. Each correct answer is worth 4 points, each incorrect subtracts 1 from the total score, and each question left blank is worth 0 points.:

```
answers = ["B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"]
total = 1
counter = 1

for line in outfile:
    student_counter = student_counter + 1
    text_line = line.split(',')
    if (text_line[counter] == answers[counter-1]):
        total = total+4
    elif text_line[counter] == ' ':
        total = total
        counter = counter +1
    else:
        total = total-1
print(total)
```

How do I edit my program to iterate over each line in the inputted file and display the highest score, lowest score, median, mode, and range?

Answer (score 2):

Python's `split(delimiter)` is your friend in this case. One possible solution is just iterating over the lines in file, splitting them and comparing them to key. `zip` function comes in handy: if you also split the key, you'll end up with two lists of the same length where one list contains the student's answers and second one correct answers.

`zip` creates a single list of tuples from these 2 lists, where each tuple contains student's answer and correct answer and you can simply compare these two.

In order to do some future calculations, easy way is saving the results to some outside structure and then doing the calculation. Code that does this can look like this:

```
key = 'B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D'.split(',')
students = {}

with open('grades', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_split = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        students[line_split[0]] = 0
        for key, answer in zip(key, line_split[1:]):
            if key == answer:
                students[line_split[0]] = students[line_split[0]] + 4
            else:
                students[line_split[0]] = students[line_split[0]] - 1

print students
```

which gives the output

{'N12345678': 100}

for your example data.

If you were to iterate over the results and do some calculations, you can do that by

```
for student, score in students:
    print score
```

but I'll leave the calculations to you so you can solve the assignment yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use dictionaries, I suggest this code as an option:

```
answers = ['B', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D']
students = {}

# Example of a line from the outfile
outfile = ["N12345678,B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"]

# This simulates the loop used to iterate over the textfile
for line in outfile:
    total = 0  # Total score for the student

    student_answers = line.split(',')  # The student and his answers

    # We enumerate each element of the student's answer sheet. We exclude his ID for obvious reasons
    for i, answer in enumerate(student_answers[1:]):
        if (answer == answers[i]):  #Correct answer
            total += 4
        elif text_line[counter] != answers[i]:  # Wrong answer
            total -= 1
        else:  # Blank answer, we pass to the next iteration
            pass

    # We finally asociate each student's ID to his score.
    students[student_answers[0]] = total

print(students)
```